# 'Posts_update' object is not iterable in django

Tags: python, django, orm

i am just try to get data from db table and show on detail page but i am getting error -'Posts_update' object is not iterable.

I have two tables posts and posts_update. in posts table i am doing CRUD operation and on each update i am adding information in posts_update table now i am trying to get information from posts_update table using mobile as a parameter but i am getting error -'Posts_update' object is not iterable.

models.py

```html
from django.db import models

class Posts(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=15,default='')

class Posts_update(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=15,default='')
```

urls.py

```html
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('create/', views.create, name='create'),
    path('detail/<int:post_mobile>', views.read, name='detail'),
    path('delete/<int:post_id>', views.delete, name='delete'),
    path('update/<int:post_id>', views.update, name='update')

]
```

views.py

```html
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib import messages
from .models import Posts
from .models import Posts_update


def index(request):
    posts = Posts.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {
        'posts': posts
    })

def create(request):
    if request.POST:
        req = request.POST
        post = Posts(title=req.get('title'), slug=slugify(req.get('title')), content=req.get('content'), mobile=req.get('mobile'))
        post.save()
        messages.success(request, 'The record was saved successfully')
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        return render(request, 'create.html')

def update(request, post_id):
    

    if request.POST:
        req = request.POST
        post = Posts.objects.get(id=post_id)
        post.title = req.get('title')
        post.slug = slugify(req.get('title'))
        post.content = req.get('content')
        post.mobile = req.get('mobile')
        post.save()
        post = Posts_update(title=req.get('title'), slug=slugify(req.get('title')), content=req.get('content'), mobile=req.get('mobile'))
        post.save()
        messages.success(request, 'The record was saved successfully')
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        post = Posts.objects.get(id=post_id)
        return render(request, 'update.html', {
            'id': post.id,
            'title': post.title,
            'slug': post.slug,
            'content': post.content,
            'mobile': post.mobile
        })

def read(request, post_mobile):
    post = Posts_update.objects.get(mobile=post_mobile)
    # post = Posts_update.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'detail.html', {
        'Posts_update': Posts_update
    })



def delete(request, post_id):
    post = Posts.objects.get(id=post_id)
    post.delete()
    messages.success(request, 'The record was deleted successfully')
    return redirect('/')
```

detail.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Crud Django - {{ title }}</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
{% block content %}
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 offset-sm-2">
                <h2 class="display-6">Detail post</h2>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col">id</th>
                          <th scope="col">title</th>
                          <th scope="col">slug</th>
                          <th scope="col">content</th>
                          <th scope="col">Mobile</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                    {% if Posts_update %}
                        {% for post in Posts_update %}
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ post.id }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ post.title }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ post.slug }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ post.content }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ post.mobile }}</td>                                    
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% else %}
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="5">No records found</td>
                            </tr>
                    {% endif %}
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  <a href="{% url 'index' %}" class="btn btn-warning">Back</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
{% endblock %}
</html>
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Crud Django</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h2 class="display-6">All Posts</h2>
                <a href="{% url 'create' %}" class="btn btn-success">Create post</a>
                {% if messages %}
                    {% for message in messages %}
                        <div class="alert alert-success mt-3 alert-dismissible fade show">
                            {{ message }}
                            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
                <div class="table-responsive mt-3">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col">id</th>
                          <th scope="col">title</th>
                          <th scope="col">slug</th>
                          <th scope="col">content</th>
                          <th scope="col">Mobile</th>
                          <th scope="col">action</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        {% if posts %}
                            {% for post in posts %}
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ post.id }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ post.title }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ post.slug }}</td>

                                    <td>{{ post.content }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ post.mobile }}</td>
                                    <th>
                                        <a href="{% url 'delete' post.id %}" class="btn btn-danger my-1">Delete</a>
                                        <a href="{% url 'detail' post.mobile %}" class="btn btn-primary my-1">Detail</a>
                                        <a href="{% url 'update' post.id %}" class="btn btn-warning my-1">Update</a>
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% else %}
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="5">No records found</td>
                            </tr>
                        {% endif %}
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.5.4/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-q2kxQ16AaE6UbzuKqyBE9/u/KzioAlnx2maXQHiDX9d4/zp8Ok3f+M7DPm+Ib6IU" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-pQQkAEnwaBkjpqZ8RU1fF1AKtTcHJwFl3pblpTlHXybJjHpMYo79HY3hIi4NKxyj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In detail.html you are iterating over context object `Posts_update`

`{% for post in Posts_update %}`

Which is just `Posts_update` model, due to views.py.
I guess you meant the `post` variable there.

Comment: Hi Dorofeev Andrey, i have also tried like- def read(request, post_mobile):
    post = Posts.objects.get(mobile=post_mobile)
    return render(request, 'detail.html', {
        'id': post.id,
        'title': post.title,
        'slug': post.slug,
        'content': post.content,
        'mobile': post.mobile
    })   but getting error :- get() returned more than one Posts -- it returned 2!